# Signing into a website using Indy TIdHTTP no longer works for me

Tags: http, delphi, indy10

Using Delphi and Indy's `TIdHTTP` component, I created a program simulating signing into a website.

Using the `TIdHTTP.Get()` method, I would get a sign-in `<form>` containing the email address and password input fields and the sign in button:

```html
<form action="/en/users/sign_in" method="post">
<input name="authenticity_token" value="9WO…r0g" />
<input name="session[email]" id="session_email" />
<input name="session[password]" id="session_password" />
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign in" />
</form>
```

I would create a `TStringList` and populate it with the `authenticity_token`, `session[email]`, `session[password]` and `commit` values. Then I would use the `TIdHTTP.Post()` method, and everything worked fine.

The site has been recently redesigned, and my code no longer works.
The `<head>` of the HTML page now contains the following:

```html
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="Y5J…5nQ" />
```

MS Edge Developers tools shows that the `POST` request parameters are `authenticity_token` populated with the `csrf-token` content value plus the `session[email]`, `session[password]` and `commit` values. Unfortunately, I am receiving a `400 Bad Request` error.

I have spend a lot of time reading about CSRF, Cookies, etc but cannot find a solution to my problem. I am not a professional coder, just an enthusiast.

Comment: Please show the actual code that is not working. You should be able to simply add the CSRF `<meta>` values to your posted `TStringList`, or HTTP `X-CSRF-...` request headers, depending on the server's setup. Note that CSRF tokens don't need to be in `<meta>`, they can also be in hidden `<form>` elements, or pretty much anywhere in the HTML that Javascript can access (see [Why CSRF token should be in meta tag and in cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473515/)). Without seeing the actual HTML, it likely has scripting which copies the `<meta>` values into the submitted form.

Comment: In addition to what Remy wrote: usually the tokens have a similar/same length, so just search for it anywhere (HTML file, JS files...) - most likely it's not that hard to get hold of it without the need to execute the whole JS.

Comment: The `<html>` of the sign-in page contains 2 tokens. One in the `<head>` and one in the sign-in `<form>` section.  **When one uses the browser (MS Edge), does the Dev Tool show everything happening between the client and the server during the `POST` method?**  The Payload tab suggests that only one of the tokens is being sent. I also use the Request Headers tab values to set the `IdHTTP.Request` properties before the `POST` method is called. It used to work.

Comment: Yes, web browsers that have built-in dev tools will show all of the raw GET/POST requests that they are sending. You can replicate those requests with `TIdHTTP`, adjusting the data values as needed. If you are seeing only 1 token being sent, then that is all the browser is sending. It's likely the one in the `<form>`, unless there is a client-side script copying the one from the `<head>` into the form submission dynamically.